# Pass JSON String in web part property [ cdata value] to Jquery Plugin

Tags: jquery, xml, json, sharepoint-2010

Currently, we are using PageProvisiong ( XML ) to build pages. I am passing a JSON string through the property value CDATA like this.

```
<property name="UseAccordion" value="false" />
            <property name="Type" value="documents" />
            <property name="Source" value="ABOUT1" />
            <property name="KeyWords" >
              <value>
                <![CDATA[

                      {"keywords": {"Keywords":"about" ,"CategoryIds":"PM"}}

                      ]]>
              </value>
            </property>
```

And I would like to read the JSON String in JQUERY plugin, as of now I can read the source property since it is simple string like this,

```
plugin.paramData = '{"source" : "' + plugin.options.Source + '", "type" : "'+    
plugin.options.type + '","}';
```

I would like to append the keywords to same paramData (this will be passed as a query string to webservice). Also, I would like to read each of those keywords and categoryIDs into class  properties . Could anyone please suggest how do I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use the code-behind of the webpart to render the jevascript to the page? Remember that webpart properties are available on the code bahind, So something like:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType()), "init-js", getScript(), true);

string getScript(){
    return "var myjsvar = " + this.Keywords + ";";
}
```

You now have created a variable named myjsvar on your page and assigned the value of keywords that you can use

Comment: I really appreciate your suggestion. But, as we are page provisioning to build pages there won't be any physical page (so no code behind). The only way it can be done is through plugin. Thank you.